# Is there any way to remove the word dynamically?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I am using below code to remove word **"USER1".** on my richtextbox1.

Is there any way to remove the word dynamically?

For example on my richtextbox1, I have below sentence and what ever user put a word inside my textbox1 **"USER1".** will be replaced with new input, so pleace that USER1 is holding on below sentence will be replaced with new input, so I need something to dynamically to remove the word.

**How can I add my textbox1 inside below code to delete user input word dynamically?**

```
Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"USER1\"[.](.+)");
richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

***Before using my code sentence is below***

```
ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;
```

**After using my code my sentence will be; but USER1 is depends on the user input and it can be change.**

```
ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question **is not clear**.

As far as I can see you want something like this

```
Regex reg = new Regex(String.Format("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"{0}\"[.](.+)",textbox1.text);
```

Comment: yes I want similar to this but doesnt delete the "USER1".  when I enter user input as USER1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void RemoveWord(string word){
  Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"" + word + "\"[.](.+)");
  richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2"); 
}
//To remove USER1, do this
RemoveWord("USER1");
//To remove USER2, do this
RemoveWord("USER2");
```

Comment: If I replace RemoveWord("USER1"); with RemoveWord(textBox1.Text); does it coing to help me? because in my case user input can be change. it is depends on the textBox1.Text and it is just a example that I put USER1 but if user put another word I need to delete that one too.

Comment: I did use like this but didn't work: RemoveWord(textBox1.Text);

Comment: @user2661591 what was the value you input in your `textBox1`? Could you be more elaborate on how it didn't work?

Comment: I put inside my textbox1 : USER1

Comment: @user2661591 and the result? just a line is OK.

Comment: after using your way result didnt change, I edit my question.

Comment: ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

Comment: @user2661591 I don't see any `USER1` in your sample input, do you mean you want to remove `ENROLLMENT`? If so you have to input the `ENROLLMENT` into your textbox.

Comment: sorry! I copied result sentence. I added my sentence. please check it out

Comment: @user2661591 it should work, be sure that you passed in the `textBox1.Text.Trim()` to prevent other spaces at the ends, like this `RemoveWord(textBox1.Text.Trim())`

Comment: @user2661591 I tested the code and it worked like a charm. To be sure that the `RemoveWord` method is called when you trigger something, I don't have any clue on why it doesn't work for you.